# Touchpad cursor goes crazy Acer aspire V11

Tags: 14.04, acer

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Laptop acer aspire V11
But time to time the cursor on screen goes crazy and move everywhere erratically
without being able to stop it (or only if i let my finger somewhere on the touch pad)

Do you know if there is a specific driver to install
or a setting somewhere to fix that?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if what you're explaining is the same as what I'm experiencing on Lenovo G5070; but I disable and re-enable touchpad with keyboard Fn-key combination.

Comment: Well i don't know about you but my cursor is moving super fast everywhere, using the Keyboard short-cut might be a temporary solution to stop this madness.
But i'm looking for a more stable and reliable solution 
to fix that once for all

Comment: UP, Nobody have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same laptop en I experience the same problem now and than. I don't have a permanent way to fix it but you can do some things to solve it when it occurs. I think the problem is in the touch pad so you can disable the touch pad with he function key and continue with a mouse or the touchscreen. I feel like it has something to do with the touch pad getting moist since I get this problem most when my hands are still a bit wet or when my laptop is very cold in a warm room which causes some condensation on the touch pad. Making sure the touch pad is dry again solves the problem most of the times.